# Replacing dynamic variable in string UNITY

Tags: regex, string, unity-game-engine, reflection

I am making a simple dialogue system, and would like to "dynamise" some of the sentences.
For exemple, I have a Sentence

> Hey Adventurer {{PlayerName}} !
>   Welcome in the world !

Now In code I am trying to replace that by the real value of the string in my game. I am doing something like this. But it doesn't work. I do have a `string PlayerName` in my component where the function is situated

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<={{)(.*?)(?=}})");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sentence);

for(int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.Log(matches[i]);
    sentence.Replace("{{"+matches[i]+"}}", this.GetType().GetField(matches[i].ToString()).GetValue(this) as string);
}
return sentence;
```

But this return me an error, even tho the match is correct.

Any idea of a way to do fix, or do it better?

Comment: String.Replace returns a new string, so sentence.Replace does not modify sentence. You have to create a new string to hold the new text after replacement. After modifying this to do that properly, this works fine for me with no error. What is the error that you are getting? We can't help you if we don't know what the error you are having is.

Comment: Also, I would avoid reflection and have a dictionary of search+replace pairs if that is just as feasible for you to do.

Comment: @adisib that is the plan in the future probably

The error was the variable I was reflecting was not public but private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would solve this.

Create a dictionary with keys as the values you wish to replace and values as what you will be replacing them to.

```
Dictionary<string, string> valuesToReplace;
valuesToReplace = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    valuesToReplace.Add("[playerName]", "Max");
    valuesToReplace.Add("[day]", "Thursday");
```

Then check the text for the values in your dictionary.
If you make sure all of your keys start with "[" and end with "]" this will be quick and easy.

```
List<string> replacements = new List<string>(); 
    //We will save all of the replacements we are about to perform here.
    //This is done so we won't be modifying the original string while working on it, which will create problems.
    //We will save them in the following format:  originalText}newText

    for(int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) //Let's loop through the entire text
    {
        int startOfVar = 9999;
        if(text[i] == '[') //We have found the beginning of a variable
        {
            startOfVar = i;
        }
        if(text[i] == ']') //We have found the ending of a variable
        {
            string replacement = text.Substring(startOfVar, i - startOfVar); //We have found the section we wish to replace
            if (valuesToReplace.ContainsKey(replacement))
                replacements.Add(replacement + "}" + valuesToReplace[replacement]); //Add the replacement we are about to perform to our dictionary
        }
    }
    //Now let's perform the replacements:

    foreach(string replacement in replacements)
    {
        text = text.Replace(replacement.Split('}')[0], replacement.Split('}')[1]); //We split our line. Remember the old value was on the left of the } and the new value was on the right
    }
```

This will also work much faster, since it allows you to add as many variables as you wish without making the code slower.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, and a [MatchEvaluator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator?view=netframework-4.7.2) delegate (untested):

```
    Dictionary<string, string> Replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Regex DialogVariableRegex = new Regex("(?<={{)(.*?)(?=}})");

    string Replace(string sentence) {

        DialogVariableRegex.Replace(sentence, EvaluateMatch);

        return sentence;
    }

    string EvaluateMatch(Match match) {

        var matchedKey = match.Value;

        if (Replacements.ContainsKey(matchedKey))
            return Replacements[matchedKey];
        else
            return ">>MISSING KEY<<";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of old now, but I figured I'd update the accepted code above.  It won't work since the start index is reset every time the loop iterates, so setting `startOfVar = i` gets completely reset by the time it hits the closing character. Plus there are problems if there's an open bracket '[' and no closing one. You can also no longer use those brackets in your text.

There's also setting the splitter to a single character.  It tests fine, but if I set my player name to "Rob}ert", that will cause problems when it performs the replacements.

Here is my updated take on the code which I've tested works in Unity:

```
    public string EvaluateVariables(string str)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> varDict = GetVariableDictionary();
        List<string> varReplacements = new List<string>();
        string matchGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        bool matched = false;

        int start = int.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == '{')
            {
                if (str[i + 1] == '$')
                {
                    start = i;
                    matched = true;
                }
            }
            else if (str[i] == '}' && matched)
            {
                string replacement = str.Substring(start, (i - start) + 1);
                if (varDict.ContainsKey(replacement))
                {
                    varReplacements.Add(replacement + matchGuid + varDict[replacement]);
                }
                start = int.MaxValue;
                matched = false;
            }
        }

        foreach (string replacement in varReplacements)
        {
            str = str.Replace(replacement.Split(new string[] { matchGuid }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0], replacement.Split(new string[] { matchGuid }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
        }

        return str;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetVariableDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> varDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        varDict.Add("{$playerName}", playerName);
        varDict.Add("{$npcName}", npcName);
        return varDict;
    }
```